# IP Cameras with API support to detect and connect for stream from outside network

Tags: home-security, ip-camera

I am looking for IP cameras which can be connected to from across the internet using information like Device ID, Credentials. Do you have any recommendations?

In this case, I would think the vendor would have some server which my application needs to connect/communicate to first with the camera identifier and credentials. And the server would have the URI for the camera, for getting the stream from the camera etc.

Comment: Considering the server loads and stuff I would be surprised if you could find it free, without paying for those cloud options.

Comment: @jan I am ok to pay. I was wondering if anyone came across such vendors.